# Mounting all USB flash disks to same directory raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, usb-drive

I'm working on a project with raspberry pi 3 (using python scripts) where i want to read mp3 files from USB flash disk, i've succeeded !

But the path of my usb is fixed, i used chdir('media/usb1') so my code will be looking to the files in this directory and the problem is that if i want to plug another usb flash disk it will be mounted to a different directory !

First i tried to put chdir('media/*') so that it will take whatever subdirectories under media but it doesn't work so now i'm thinking maybe there is a way to make all usb flash disks to be mounted in the same directory "usb1" this way i won't have to change my path every time i have another usb plugged in!

And if i have 2 usbs plugged in at the same time,Automatically the first one will be at usb1 directory and the second will be at usb2 directory!

If anyone have any suggestions it would be great !

Thank you !